# Let hn (n ≥ 0) denote the number of n-digit integers such that each digit is odd and each of the digits 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 occurs an odd number of times.

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Let hn (n ≥ 0) denote the number of n-digit integers such that each digit is odd and each of the digits 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 occurs an odd number of times.

a) Find h0, h1, h2, h3, h4, & h5.

b) Find hn in closed form.

I couldn't figure out how to solve for part a, thus, I tried solving for part b first so that I might be able to get part a after I solve for the equation. For part b, after solving for the exponential generating function {which is (exp(x)-exp(-x)/32)^5}, I found that h_n = 5^n + 5*3^n + 10 - 10(-1)^n + 5(-3)^n - (-5)^n. However, when I plug in for n=0..5 to get the answers for part a, I get a zero for every n I plug into h_n. Now, I am confused and I don't know how to solve this.

Could you please show me how to solve this with an explanation so that I know what is going on?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: For $h(1), h(2), h(3), h(4)$ I think the answer should actually be zero, right? Because with $\leq 4$ digits you cannot build an integer such that digits $1, 3, 5, 7, 9$ all occur an odd number of times (because at least one of them occurs $0$ times, which is even).

Comment: Also, for $h(5)$ each of $1, 3, 5, 7, 9$ has to appear exactly once. Thus there are $5!$ such numbers.

Comment: Thanks, araomis, but if only 1 is included as the digit, then that means that there is one odd integer and it is occurred once, thus occurred odd number of times too. This means that having 1 would satisfy the conditions stated in the problem. 
Would we still have h(1)..h(4)=0? If so, why? (I still don't understand the logic behind it)

Comment: Ok. It seems I interpret "each of the digits 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 occurs an odd number of times" in a different way that you do. In your example digits $3, 5, 7, 9$ do not appear i.e. they appear $0$ number of times (which is odd). So what condition do you mean? Do integers $1, 3, 5, 7, 9$ have to appear collectively an odd number of times? Then this would mean that $h(2) = h(4) = 0$.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I meant that 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 don't have to be appear collectively. The conditions I was talking about are that there should be an odd digit and it should occur an odd number of times which is the case when there is only the number 1.